# Javascript automatically rounding to nearest whole number

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to programmatically increase the width of a `div` by a set percentage in a loop. I have a div which contains a progress bar that I am attempting to increase by X percent with each iteration. My code is below.

```
var progressWidth = $('#progress').width();
var progressContainerWidth = $('#progressBar').width();

var currentWidth = Math.round((progressWidth / progressContainerWidth) * 100);
var newWidth = parseFloat(currentWidth) + parseFloat(0.6);

$('#progress').width(newWidth + '%');
```

I'm attempting to increase the width percent by 0.6 every time. For some reason it's automatically rounding 0.6 to 1. So my starting width is 10% and it's going 10.6, 11.6, 12.6, etc...

Why is it adding 1.0 and not 0.6?

Comment: You may want to check out the `<progress>` element. But from what I can see it seems like you're rounding up and then adding 0.6.

Comment: because you used Math.round on it?

Comment: What is the value of `currentWidth`

Comment: @chbchb55 Yeah, that's what's going on. The third line is rounding to the nearest whole number rather than to two decimal places. Once I fix that it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't round your percentages

Currently, you're running `Math.round` on say `10.6` which turns it into `11`. Instead, just add `0.6` without rounding.

```js
const currentWidth = progressWidth / progressContainerWidth * 100; // 10.6
const newWdith = currentWidth + 0.6; // 11.2
```